# How to build a list of words which works just by referring

Tags: glossaries

I want to write my thesis in my native language (Persian). But people don't agree with each other on the translation of some technical word. I have a set of macros which correctly defines entries in the glossary, which I don't want to interfere with the working of them.

```
\newglossarystyle{mylistFa}{
\glossarystyle{list}\addcontentsline{toc} 
 {chapter}{واژه‌نامه فارسی به انگلیسی}
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1] 
 {\section*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}}
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace* 
  {-1cm}}
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]     
 {\noindent\glstarget{##1}{##2}\dotfill 
 \space ##3 \\}
 \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6] 
  {\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5} 
  {##6}}
  }


  \newglossarystyle{mylistEn}{
  \glossarystyle{list}\addcontentsline{toc} 
  {chapter}{واژه‌نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1] 
  {\begin{LTR} \section* 
  {\lr{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}} \end{LTR}}
   \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace* 
  {-1cm}}
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]     
  {\noindent\glstarget{##1}{##3}\dotfill 
  \space ##2 \\}
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6] 
   {\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5} 
  {##6}}
  }

  % تعریف دو نمونه واژه نامه
  \newglossary[glg]{english}{gls}{glo} 
  {واژه‌نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
  \newglossary[blg]{persian}{bls}{blo} 
  {واژه‌نامه فارسی به انگلیسی}

  % توسط این دستور واژه مورد نظر در متن، 
  هر دو واژه نامه و پاورقی می آید.
  \newcommand{\inpdic}[2]{
   \newglossaryentry{fa-#1} 
   {type=persian,name={#1}, sort= 
   {#1},description={\lr{#2}}}\gls{fa- 
    #1}\LTRfootnote{#2}
    \newglossaryentry{en-#1} 
   {type=english,name={\lr{#2}}, sort= 
   {#2},description={#1}}\glsuseri{en-#1}
   \!\!\!\!}

   % توسط این دستور واژه مورد نظر در متن، 
   هر دو واژه نامه  می آید.
  \newcommand{\indic}[2]{
   \newglossaryentry{fa-#1} 
   {type=persian,name={#1}, sort= 
   {#1},description={\lr{#2}}}\gls{fa-#1}
   \newglossaryentry{en-#1} 
   {type=english,name={\lr{#2}}, sort= 
   {#2},description={#1}}\glsuseri{en-#1}
   }

   % توسط این دستور واژه مورد نظر فقط در 
   هر دو واژه نامه  می آید.
   \newcommand{\ingls}[2]{
    \newglossaryentry{fa-#1} 
   {type=persian,name={#1}, sort= 
   {#1},description={\lr{#2}}}\glsuseri{fa- 
   #1}
   \newglossaryentry{en-#1} 
   {type=english,name={\lr{#2}}, sort= 
   {#2},description={#1}}\glsuseri{en-#1}
    }

   \makeglossaries
   \glsdisablehyper
```

I use these macros like the following

```
\inpdic{احساس}{emotion}
```

But I want to define all of the entries in the glossary at the beginning of my thesis and then using this table, I just retrieve from this table the entry I want. In this way, all of the translation of a word in my thesis will be the same and when I want to change an entry, I didn't have to change it in all of my thesis.

How should I do it?

Here is a short compilable code. It compiles, but unfortunately, it doesn't print the glossary. Which I don't know why. 
    \documentclass{minimal}

```
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossarystyle{mylistFa}{
\glossarystyle{list}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{واژه‌نامه فارسی به       
 انگلیسی}
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\section*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}}
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace*{-1cm}}
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]     {\noindent\glstarget{##1}    
 {##2}\dotfill \space ##3 \\}
\renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4}    
 {##5}{##6}}
 }


\newglossarystyle{mylistEn}{
\glossarystyle{list}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{واژه‌نامه انگلیسی به 
 فارسی}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\begin{LTR} \section* 
{\lr{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}} \end{LTR}}
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace*{-1cm}}
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]     {\noindent\glstarget{##1} 
{##3}\dotfill \space ##2 \\}
\renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4} 
{##5}{##6}}
}

% تعریف دو نمونه واژه نامه
\newglossary[glg]{english}{gls}{glo}{واژه‌نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
\newglossary[blg]{persian}{bls}{blo}{واژه‌نامه فارسی به انگلیسی}

% توسط این دستور واژه مورد نظر در متن، هر دو واژه نامه و پاورقی می آید.
\newcommand{\inpdic}[2]{
\newglossaryentry{fa-#1}{type=persian,name={#1}, sort={#1},description= 
 {\lr{#2}}}\gls{fa-#1}\LTRfootnote{#2}
\newglossaryentry{en-#1}{type=english,name={\lr{#2}}, sort={#2},description= 
{#1}}\glsuseri{en-#1}
\!\!\!\!}

% توسط این دستور واژه مورد نظر در متن، هر دو واژه نامه  می آید.
 \newcommand{\indic}[2]{
 \newglossaryentry{fa-#1}{type=persian,name={#1}, sort={#1},description= 
 {\lr{#2}}}\gls{fa-#1}
 \newglossaryentry{en-#1}{type=english,name={\lr{#2}}, sort={#2},description= 
 {#1}}\glsuseri{en-#1}
 }

 % توسط این دستور واژه مورد نظر فقط در هر دو واژه نامه  می آید.
 \newcommand{\ingls}[2]{
 \newglossaryentry{fa-#1}{type=persian,name={#1}, sort={#1},description= 
 {\lr{#2}}}\glsuseri{fa-#1}
 \newglossaryentry{en-#1}{type=english,name={\lr{#2}}, sort={#2},description= 
 {#1}}\glsuseri{en-#1}
 }

 \makeglossaries
 \glsdisablehyper

 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{xepersian}
 \settextfont{XB Niloofar}
 \begin{document}

  این فقط یک آزمایش است 

  \ingls{احساس}{emotion}

 \makeatletter

 \indic{دانش}{Knowledge}

 \glossarystyle{mylistFa}
 \printglossary[type=persian]

 \glossarystyle{mylistEn}
 \printglossary[type=english]


 % دقت کنید که این نمایه براساس حروف انگلیسی هم قابل مرتب شدن است، و آن‌ 
 را به عنوان نمایه و واژه‌نامه به طور همزمان نیز می‌توان به کار برد.
 \renewcommand\glossaryname{نمایه}
 \glossarystyle{list}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{نمایه}
 \printglossary

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First of all** you should see [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448387/glossary-and-abbreviation-showing-problem-in-xepersianshown-in-blank-pages/455091#455091) for **correctly compiling**.
**Secondly**, you will have the `Deprecated command \glossarystyle` **warning**, after the compiling. With the below structure you can remove this warning:

```
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{glossaries}{Deprecated command}
```

So your codes is the same as following:

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=magenta]{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy,acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{glossaries}{Deprecated command}
\newglossarystyle{mylistFa}{
    \glossarystyle{list}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{واژه‌نامه فارسی به       
        انگلیسی}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\section*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace*{-1cm}}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]     {\noindent\glstarget{##1}    
        {##2}\dotfill \space ##3 \\}
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4}    
        {##5}{##6}}
}


\newglossarystyle{mylistEn}{
    \glossarystyle{list}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{واژه‌نامه انگلیسی به 
        فارسی}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\begin{LTR} \section* 
            {\lr{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}} \end{LTR}}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vspace*{-1cm}}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]     {\noindent\glstarget{##1} 
        {##3}\dotfill \space ##2 \\}
    \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{\glossaryentryfield{##2}{##3}{##4} 
        {##5}{##6}}
}

% تعریف دو نمونه واژه نامه
\newglossary[glg]{english}{gls}{glo}{واژه‌نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
\newglossary[blg]{persian}{bls}{blo}{واژه‌نامه فارسی به انگلیسی}

% توسط این دستور واژه مورد نظر در متن، هر دو واژه نامه و پاورقی می آید.
\newcommand{\inpdic}[2]{
\newglossaryentry{fa-#1}{type=persian,name={#1}, sort={#1},description= 
        {\lr{#2}}}\gls{fa-#1}\LTRfootnote{#2}
\newglossaryentry{en-#1}{type=english,name={\lr{#2}}, sort={#2},description= 
{#1}}\glsuseri{en-#1}
\!\!\!\!}

% توسط این دستور واژه مورد نظر در متن، هر دو واژه نامه  می آید.
\newcommand{\indic}[2]{
\newglossaryentry{fa-#1}{type=persian,name={#1}, sort={#1},description= 
{\lr{#2}}}\gls{fa-#1}
\newglossaryentry{en-#1}{type=english,name={\lr{#2}}, sort={#2},description= 
{#1}}\glsuseri{en-#1}
}

% توسط این دستور واژه مورد نظر فقط در هر دو واژه نامه  می آید.
\newcommand{\ingls}[2]{
    \newglossaryentry{fa-#1}{type=persian,name={#1}, sort={#1},description= 
        {\lr{#2}}}\glsuseri{fa-#1}
    \newglossaryentry{en-#1}{type=english,name={\lr{#2}}, sort={#2},description= 
        {#1}}\glsuseri{en-#1}
}

\makeglossaries
\glsdisablehyper
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1.3]{PGaramond}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.2]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
این فقط یک آزمایش است

\noindent
\inpdic{قابل اعتماد}{believable}\\
\indic{دانش}{Knowledge}
\ingls{احساس}{emotion}
\glossarystyle{mylistFa}
\printglossary[type=persian]
\glossarystyle{mylistEn}
\printglossary[type=english]


    % دقت کنید که این نمایه براساس حروف انگلیسی هم قابل مرتب شدن است، و آن‌ 
    %را به عنوان نمایه و واژه‌نامه به طور همزمان نیز می‌توان به کار برد.
\renewcommand\glossaryname{نمایه}
\glossarystyle{list}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{نمایه}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

---

And your outputs is the same as below:

---

[image]

### [image]

### [image]

### [image]

Good luck.

Comment: I have this output. What I want is to have a list of keywords, somewhere in the tex code and then instead of explicitly using the word, use the word from this table. In this, if I want to update the translation of a word, I don't have too go into all of my text.

Comment: @user85361 . Unfortunately, I did not understand what you mean. Please attach an image of what you are asking for.